# Simple XCTest for UITest is failing all the time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

I start a new project from File -> New -> project

I add a button to ViewController.

I open UITest folder which created by xcode by default. Run the test code.

It fails:

```
2016-03-16 12:57:09.191 XCTRunner[3511:150419] Continuing to run tests in the background with task ID 1
    t =    10.18s         Assertion Failure: UI Testing Failure - Failed to background test runner.
/Users/Bernard/Desktop/ExampleTestApplication/ExampleTestApplicationUITests/test2.m:27: error: -[test2 testExample] : UI Testing Failure - Failed to background test runner.
2016-03-16 12:57:12.789 XCTRunner[3511:150419] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception '_XCTestCaseInterruptionException', reason: 'Interrupting test'
```

Now I add a break point as follow:

[image]

Now test is successful! Anyone can explain the reason?

Comment: i have faced the same issue (kind of) some time back.I noticed that this crash might be related to the app launching handling. Apple seems to have set a timeout for the testing instance and if the instance didn't get response from your app before the timeout, the instance will be terminated and the app crashes at the `[app launch];` position.

Comment: @Bluewings Am I able to change this timeout time and my app has only one view!!!

Comment: AFAIK we dont have access to change the time out.

Comment: @Bluewings How did you fix this problem then?

Comment: i am not sure this is what exact issue you have. But it got fixed when i tested the same code in OS X server, weird but now working fine

Comment: as for me a workaround is to build the app before first running test.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing same issues and none of the available solutions worked for me. Issue was not letting app to attach to the simulator itself.
I checked the log and saw that i did a mistake in code while locating the element. for Predicate instead of BEGINSWITH i wrote STARTSWITH and this was stopping the app to get attached.
So check your logs in the test report to get the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error happening when the iOS simulator was already launched (which may not necessarily mean you can see it in the OS X dock). You can check the state of the various simulators using the `simctl` command.

I.e.

```
xcrun simctl list devices
```

Then, ensure that any devices listed as "Booted" are shutdown:

```
xcrun simctl shutdown <device-udid-here>
```

Then, try running your UI tests again.